# While uploading this to testflight, getting "Com.amazonaws.sdk.ios.awsresources" missing code signing entitlements in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, aws-sdk

I am using AWS framework and its working fine, I added it manually. But, the issue is, while uploading app to test

> ERROR ITMS-90166: “Missing code signing entitlements. No entitlements
>   found in bundle ‘com.amazongaws.sdk.ios.AWSResources’ for executable
>   ‘path’
>
> ERROR ITMS-90171: “Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
>   “AWSLex.framework/AWSResources.bundle/AWSResources’ is not permitted.

Can anyone guide me how to fix and upload to test flight.

Answer (score 0):

**For ERROR ITMS-90166:**

- Try removing the CFBundleExecutable key from the Info.plist of the
  resource bundle. Clean & build the project.
- Before Archiving confirm that you are using an AppStore Distribution
  Provisioning Profile. Go to Build Settings > Code Signing.

**For ERROR ITMS-90171:**

- Remove concerned library from everywhere within your project. Also
  from "Copy Bundle Resources" and "Embedded Libraries".
- Add it to Link Binary with Libraries build phase.
- Don’t add to target's Copy Bundle Resources build phase.
- Clean, build and archive the project.

Comment: did u understand the issue first, im using framework, its doesnt have any plist, i have only main plist only.